# Ошибка TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes

Tags: python, discord.py, pillow

Код:

```
guild = bot.get_guild(1028696149860827156)
    voiceid = member.voice.channel.id
    voice_object = bot.get_channel(member.voice.channel.id)
    generalChannel = member.voice.channel

    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, name="CRASH FACEIT - in Standoff 2")

    len_members = len(voice_object.members)

    banner_image = Image.open("banner.png")



    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(banner_image)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('Roboto-Medium.ttf', size=55)


    draw.text((0, 0), f"{len_members}", fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font)

    banner_image.save('banner.png')
    
    await guild.edit(banner="banner.png")
```

проблема в том что функция `await guild.edit(banner="banner.png")` читает banner.png как байты, а такого быть не должно.
Как обратится как к файлу из метода guild.edit?

Answer (score 0):

```
banner_image = Image.open(open("banner.png", "rb"))
```

попробуйте передать так, либо явно закройте открытие файла, а потом откройте средствами Питона без использования модуля в режиме 'rb'.